# DataTable.Load Method not working when there´s update only with new records

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, datatable

I have a SQL table that needs to be updated with data from another table.

If there is a new record it works and inserts the new record, but if there is an update to an existing record, it won´t update the name in the record.

The example is in VB.Net, but you are welcome to reply with C# code.

```
        Dim workMembers As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim extMembers As New DataTableReader(GetExternalMembers())

        Using con As New SqlConnection(c.ConnectionString)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter("Select id, name from members", con)
                sda.Fill(workMembers)
                workMembers.Load(extMembers, LoadOption.PreserveChanges)
                sda.Update(workMembers)
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the dataadapter fill does not fill the primary key info and without a primary key to match against, the Load will just append the records.  Try adding ``sda.FillSchema(workMembers, SchemaType.Source)`` before ``sda.Fill(workMembers)``.

Answer (score 0):

The workMembers.Load loads the records from the external table and marks them as unchanged because there is already a record present in the table.  See [DataTable.Load Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), second paragraph under remarks.  You either need to loop through the records and set each modified record to Modified using the SetModified method.  TnTinMn is correct that your table definition needs to have a primary key appended to the definition in order to support the merge. See [DataTable.PrimaryKey Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)